# color meanings when shapely polygons are displayed

Tags: python, shapely

Is there a signification for colors (red, green) when you display a shapely polygon object ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a significance to the color.

The images displayed are created from the output of the `.svg` method. Both multipolygon and polygon have this piece of code:

```py
if fill_color is None:
    fill_color = "#66cc99" if self.is_valid else "#ff3333"
```

Thus the color significance originates from the validity of the objects.

From the [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.is_valid):
"A valid Polygon may not possess any overlapping exterior or interior rings. A valid MultiPolygon may not collect any overlapping polygons. Operations on invalid features may fail."

Therefore the multipolygon is not valid in your example but the polygon is.

Comment: Thank you.
Any idea why the multipolygon is not valid ?
`multipolygon = MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]), Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])])`

Even with counter clock wise order, the multipolygon is displayed in red.

Comment: you could use the function inside shapely to explain that for you (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#diagnostics).

In this case, it is because shapely considers the polygons to be overlapping, because they share a boundary with infinite points.